# Copy an int array, replacing all values less than x with 12

Tags: java

```
public class ArrayExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = 3;
    int d =2;
    System.out.println("c is " + c + " d is " + d);
    swapInts(3,2);
        int [] a = {1,2,3};
        int [] b = {2,2,3};
        int [] x = {3,45,17,2,-1,44,9,23,67,2,-6,-23,-100,12,5,1212};
        int e = 12;
        System.out.println();
        for ( int z: a){
            System.out.print( z + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
        for ( int y: b){
            System.out.print( y + " ");
        }
        swapIntArrays (a,b);
        System.out.println();
        for ( int z: x){
            System.out.print( z + " ");
        }

        replaceLessThan(x,e);
    }


    public static void replaceLessThan(int[] x, int e) {    
        System.out.println();
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter<x.length; counter++){
            if ( x[counter] < e){
                 x[counter] = e;

            }
            System.out.print (x[counter] + " ");
        }

    }


    public static void swapInts(int c, int d){
        int temp = c;
        c=d;
        d=temp;
        System.out.println("c is " + c + " c is " + d);


    }

    public static void swapIntArrays (int []a, int []b){
        System.out.println();
        for(int i1=0; i1 < a.length; i1++){
            int temp = a[i1];
            a[i1] = b[i1];
            b[i1]= temp;

            System.out.print(a[i1] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();

        for(int i1=0; i1 < b.length; i1++){
            System.out.print(b[i1] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

I want to pass the array `x` to the method and use array `y` to catch the returned value. I'm trying to get a method similar to the `replaceLessthan` that returns an array with the results, leaving the original array unaltered. For example print `x` before the method is called and then print both `x` and `y` after calling the method.

Comment: What's your question? (Please get rid of the javascript code snippets.)

Comment: I wrote a method  called replacelessthan to replace all values in array x that are less than 12 with 12. My question is how would I utilize a method which is similar but returns an array with results, leaving the original array unaltered. So if i passed array x to the method and use array y to catch the returned value, i want to print x before i call the method and then print both x and y after calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] copyAndReplaceLessThan(int[] x, int e) {    
    System.out.println();
    int[] results = new int[x.length];
    for (int counter = 0 ; counter<x.length; counter++){
        if ( x[counter] < e){
             results[counter] = e;
        } else {
             results[counter] = x[counter];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
    return results;
}
```

Comment: interesting from my code int[]x was run through the method replaceLessThan which out put the array with all numbers less than 12 being replaced. I want to write a second method which is similar but returns an array with the results, leaving the original array unaltered. is that what this does. I also want to test the method in main, by printing both the original array and the returned array which the method copyAndReplaceLessThan returns

Comment: That's what it does. If you read the code, you see there is a second array created called results, which is initialized to the same size as the original. Then it iterates over the original, copying all bytes that are >= e to result, and replacing the smaller values as it copies.  It prints both arrays at the end and then returns the new array with the replacements made.

Comment: for the arrays.toString i get an error arrays cannot be resolved do i have to import?

Comment: I am new to java so I have never used arrays.toString is there another way to do this or is this the only and most correct way?

Comment: or is that just to fomat output into brackets?

Comment: java.lang.Arrays.toString is the standard (and easiest) way to format arrays for printing.  The JavaDoc is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: @user4679086  If this works for you, please remember to click the answer button. Thx.